# A Javascript function calling a Java function

Tags: javascript, java

I have this code wherein I want it only to run when clicked. However, the problem is that the scriptlet `notificationDAO.read()` is always running whether or not the button is clicked.

Html:

```
            <div style="word-wrap: break-word;">
                <li>
                    <a onclick="read();">
                        <span class="message" style="color: gray;">

                        </span>
                        <span class="subject">
                            <span class="time" style="color: gray;">
                                Mark All as Read
                            </span>
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </div>
```

Javascript:

```
function read() {
    <%
        notificationDAO.read(((User)session.getAttribute("user")).getEmployeeID());
    %>
}
```

Comment: this is completely expected behaviour - code between `<%` and `%>` is run on the server as part of the page generating process. html isn't bidirectional

Comment: @JaromandaX So this means codes between `<%` and `%>` always runs?

Comment: yes, because code betwen `<%` and `%>` is run on the server when generating the html content to send to the browser

Comment: @JaromandaX Ohh.. Thank you